# LockSupport parkUntil with blocker

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, locking

I am trying to understand what would be the purpose of a parameter for method: `LockSupport::parkUntil`. Let me give an example of what I mean here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object blockedOn = new Object();
    System.out.println(blockedOn.hashCode());

    Thread parked = new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("parking the thread");

        long howMuch = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 1000;

        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < howMuch) {
            LockSupport.parkUntil(blockedOn, howMuch);
        }

        System.out.println("parked the thread");
    });

    parked.start();
    sleepOneSecond();

    Object on = LockSupport.getBlocker(parked);
    System.out.println(on.hashCode());

}

private static void sleepOneSecond() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

There are actually a few questions, if someone wants to help me understand this. First, is that `while loop`, I don't see any other means to get away from (documentation from `LockSupport::parkUntil`):

> The call spuriously (that is, for no reason) returns.

So, I can only assume that `LockSupport::parkUntil` can fail, for no reason; as such I am forced to wrap this into a loop.

The next question I have is what would be the purpose of that `blockedOn` parameter? I do understand that when waiting long enough, I could do:

```
Object on = LockSupport.getBlocker(parked);
```

i.e.: find out the *current* state of the Object I am blocked on, and as such, somehow react to that. I was thinking I could interrupt the blocked thread (of course it has to support interruptions), but is there any other reason may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, this loop is the same you'd use for a [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), ensuring that the "state predicate" is still satisfied when you exit the "parked" mode.

As for your second question, the `blocker` object is really only used for debugging purposes. The [Javadoc states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html)

> The three forms of park each also support a blocker object parameter.
>   This object is recorded while the thread is blocked to permit
>   monitoring and diagnostic tools to identify the reasons that threads
>   are blocked.

Note that the [`unpark`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark(java.lang.Thread)) method does not need the `blocker` object, suggesting that it isn't used as part of the parking mechanism (ie. unrelated to the permit). In fact, you can park multiple threads with the same `blocker` object.

Comment: A simple example is doing the builtin thread dump (CTRL + BRK on Windows) and you will see something like `java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000070f8a18e0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkUntil(java.base@11/LockSupport.java:275)`